# Permissions to purge Azure Key Vault on delete

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I'm building a Terraform infra with Azure DevOps, and I have a key vault in my infra. when trying to destroy the environment (locally or in the pipeline) terraform returns the following error:

```
Error: keyvault.VaultsClient#PurgeDeleted: Failure sending request: StatusCode=403
     -- Original Error: Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client 'my-email' with
     object id 'my-object-id' does not have authorization to perform action
     'Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action' over scope
     '/subscriptions/subscription-id' or the scope is invalid.
     If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
```

This error shows although I have `owner/contributor roles over the resource group where this kv is provisioned`, and I have `Key Vault adminitrator/contributor in the subscription level`. Can someone enlighten me on what role (more restricted is better) is needed to avoid this issue in the future?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one test user and assigned **same roles** as you like below:

[image]

Now I logged in to Azure Portal using **test user's** credentials and tried to purge the deleted key vault as below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Key vaults -> Manage deleted vaults -> Select Subscription -> Select key vault -> Purge -> Delete***

[image]

When I clicked on **Delete**, it gave me ***same error*** as you like below:

[image]

> To **purge** a soft deleted key vault, user requires **`role`** that
> includes permission like
> *Microsoft.KeyVault/locations/deletedVaults/purge/action*. Please note that, only **`Subscription Owner`** will have that permission.

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign **Owner** role to the user at subscription level.

[image]

When I tried the same after getting **`Subscription Owner`** role, I'm able to **purge** that deleted key vault successfully like below:

[image]

If you don't want to assign **`Subscription Owner`** role, you can create a **custom RBAC role** by including required permissions and assign it to the user based on your requirement.

**References:**

[Azure Key Vault recovery overview | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-portal&WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault#prerequisites)

[Azure custom roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles#steps-to-create-a-custom-role)

Comment: Thank you @Sridevi, is there a way to create custom rbac roles without upgrading to Premium P1 or P2 license?

Comment: You need to upgrade to Premium licenses only when you are creating Azure AD custom roles.